# JavaScript Dynamically Create Object with Multiple Properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically create a chained JS object from an array, does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

I might have `value.dog.cat = 'hello'`, and I'd like to access that variable.

**/UPDATE**

```
item = ['dog', 'cat']
```

How do I dynamically Create:

```
value['dog']['cat']
```

Any vanilla JS or jQuery would be cool.

I can't figure this out, because If I do a loop, eg:

```
new_value = {};
for (var i = 0; i < item.length(); i++) {
  new_value += [item[i]; // This doesn't make sense
}
```

Comment: So you want it to be an object all the way through?

Comment: how should the JSON finally look like?

Comment: Yes, `value` is an existing object, which I'd like to turn into `value['dog']['cat'] `for example, that way it will grab the right property from `value`.

Comment: So why don't you include that in the question....

Comment: Okay I added an Update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to loop. Simple way is with reduce.

```js
var details = {
    dog : {
       cat : "hello world"
    }
};

var item = ['dog', 'cat'];

var value = item.reduce( function (prev, cur) {
                return prev[cur]; //|| {}; Might want to include the commented out part if keys might not be defined
            }, details);

console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**Array.prototype.reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the object or get the value

```js
var itemArray = ['dog', 'cat'];

var itemObject = {};

itemArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
  if (!a[b]) {
    a[b] = {};
  }
  return a[b];
}, itemObject);

console.log(itemObject);

itemObject.dog.cat = 'test';
var value = itemArray.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a[b];
}, itemObject);

console.log(value);
```

Comment: you are possibly overwriting some former properties.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood the question right then

```
var new_value = {};
for (var i = 1; i < item.length; i++) 
{
  new_value[item[i-1]] = item[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `value` is an object, and `value.dog` is also an object with a property `cat`, you can indeed access `value.dog.cat` as `value['dog']['cat']`. Properties of objects can be accessed as string indexes, and you basically had it right. The only issue I saw in your question was the way in which you assigned properties to `new_value` in the first place.

Comment: Yes sorry, I wasn't clear -- I want to GET data from the `value` (JSON), not create new objects if that makes sense?

Comment: Oh, so the array provides strings, and the strings correspond to the names of properties in the object?

Comment: Yessir, I added an update to try to explain it more clearly :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
function setObject(o, p, v) {
    p.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
        if (i === aa.length - 1) {
            o[a] = v;
        } else {
            o[a] = o[a] || {};
            o = o[a];
        }
    });
}

var item = ['dog', 'cat'],
    value = {};

setObject(value, item, 'hello') 
document.write(value.dog.cat);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(value, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```